# Information about urlib2 and ddos/banning of ip address

Tags: python

I'm currently using Python, making urlib2 open and read requests and saving the html code to a file. If I do this repeadly will they ban my IP address? Can someone explain what a ddos attack is and if what I'm doing is the same as a crawler/spider?

Comment: DDOS stands for "distributed denial of service", and is caused by many distributed sources making automated requests with the intention of disrupting the target. What you're doing is just reading a web page; I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: A web crawler is a program that not only reads a page, but parses out all the links from that page to other pages and also reads those.